# Jquery Date Picker Event

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-events

I've Javascript to create element input text box to store jQuery date picker, but it doesn't work:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $( "#pohdddt" ).datepicker({showOtherMonths: true,selectOtherMonths: true,dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',showOn: 'button',buttonImage: "<?php echo base_url()?>icons/cal.gif", buttonImageOnly: true, showAnim: 'slideDown', duration: 'fast'});
});


var cell = document.createElement("td");
    var theInput = document.createElement('input');
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'select date ');
            img.setAttribute('class', 'ui-datepicker-trigger');
            img.setAttribute('src',base_url_no_index+'icons/cal.gif');
            
            theInput.setAttribute('id', 'pohdddt'+i);
            theInput.setAttribute('name', 'pohdddt');
            theInput.setAttribute('value', '<?php echo date('d.m.Y'); ?>');
            theInput.setAttribute('size', '10');
            theInput.setAttribute('class','hasDatepicker');

            cell.appendChild(theInput);
            cell.appendChild(img);
            row.appendChild(cell);
```

How to call jQuery event `Onclick` when this element is created?
If so I'll create `var Ahref = document.createElement('a');`.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why not using jQuery for everything?

Comment: what requirement is that? You can use a library, but only for 30% of the code?

Comment: Not really, i've solved this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606196/how-jquery-javascript-dynamically-add-td-table , but inside a texbox is jquery datepicker. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#target').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

html code

```
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

for complete info go through http://api.jquery.com/click/